# iphone : How to rotate a rectangle image with touch events?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

transform a  square image or round image is easy to do...

But what if a rectangle image ???

This is the image I want to transform with touch event .

[image]

The circle center is (30 , 236)  , if I touch any place on the screen

Imageview will transform the arrow to my touch point.

But the circle center still the same place .

I try to transform the image use a test angle

It will become like this ...

[image]

How to adjust the image ?

Also the code is here

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGRect arrowImageRect = CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 15.0f, 220.0f);
    arrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:arrowImageRect];
    [arrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    arrow.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:arrow];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Position X: %f \n, Y: %f",touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, ?????? );
}
```

The ?????? part should be the last solution ...

Or Maybe I need to resize the imageview ???

Thanks for any reply or answer :-)

Webber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the final solution I figure this problem

check this code

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];

    [self transformSpinnerwithTouches:touch];
}

-(void)transformSpinnerwithTouches:(UITouch *)touchLocation
{
    CGPoint touchLocationpoint = [touchLocation locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint PrevioustouchLocationpoint = [touchLocation previousLocationInView:self.view];
    //origin is the respective piont from that i gonna measure the angle of the current position with respective to previous position ....
    CGPoint origin;
    origin.x = arrow.center.x;
    origin.y = arrow.center.y;
    CGPoint previousDifference = [self vectorFromPoint:origin toPoint:PrevioustouchLocationpoint];
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(arrow.transform, 1, 1);
    CGFloat previousRotation = atan2(previousDifference.y, previousDifference.x);
    CGPoint currentDifference = [self vectorFromPoint:origin toPoint:touchLocationpoint];
    CGFloat currentRotation = atan2(currentDifference.y, currentDifference.x);
    CGFloat newAngle = currentRotation- previousRotation;
    temp1 = temp1 + newAngle;
    //NSLog(@"temp1 is %f",temp1);
    //NSLog(@"Angle:%F\n",(temp1*180)/M_PI);
    newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(newTransform, newAngle);
    [self animateView:arrow toPosition:newTransform];
}
-(void)animateView:(UIView *)theView toPosition:(CGAffineTransform) newTransform
{
arrow.transform = newTransform;
}

-(CGPoint)vectorFromPoint:(CGPoint)firstPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)secondPoint
{
    CGFloat x = secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x;
    CGFloat y = secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y;
    CGPoint result = CGPointMake(x, y);
    //NSLog(@"%f %f",x,y);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation about transform method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4):

> The origin of the transform is the value of the center property, or the layer’s anchorPoint property if it was changed. (Use the layer property to get the underlying Core Animation layer object.) The default value is CGAffineTransformIdentity.

So you should be able to set the center of your rotation this way!

And for determining the rotation angle, use the `atan2` or `atan2f` function:

```
float angleInRadians = atan2f(touchPoint.y-circleCenter.y , touchPoint.x-circleCenter.x);
```

Comment: Just use it instead of your '?????' in your code above, that's what is expected as the second parameter of the CGAffineTransformRotate (read the doc ;))

Comment: Ok , Thanks ... But the result is not right ...
Let me read the doc first

Comment: Of course you have to substract M_PI_2 to  angleInRadians (or sthg similar), as angleInRadians will be the angle between the horizontal axis to the touched point but your image is vertical... and maybe invert its value too if your rotation is inverted.

Comment: I think I need to use anchorPoint , but can you tell me how to set it ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html
This is what I found

Comment: Yes great doc. Then use `arrow.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(...,...)`. Of course don't forget to add the QuartzCore framework to your project -- and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can re set the center after transform.

```
CGPoint centerBeforeTransform = view.center;
//your transform code
view.center = centerBeforeTransform;
```